# Summing date differences in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a really basic diary application.  I have the following model in SQLAlchemy:

```
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('category.id')),
    Column('entry_id', Integer, ForeignKey('entry.id'))
)

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), unique=True)
    entries = relationship('Entry', secondary=association_table,
                           back_populates='categories')

class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entry'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String(200))
    started = Column(DateTime)
    ended = Column(DateTime)
    categories = relationship('Category', secondary=association_table,
                              back_populates='entries')
```

I would like to get all entries tagged with the category 'work', and then group them by `Entry.text` (which will be the project name).  I basically want to see how long I've worked on each project. So I write the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
# s is the Session
work = s.query(Category).filter(Category.name=='work').first()
projects = (s.query(Entry.text, 
                    func.sum(Entry.ended-Entry.started)
                         .label('duration'))
              .filter(Entry.categories.contains(work))
              .group_by(Entry.text)
              .order_by('duration desc'))
```

This seems like it should work; in fact, it does when I run it against the MySQL db directly:

```
>>> print str(projects)
SELECT entry.text AS entry_text, sum(entry.ended - entry.started) AS duration 
FROM entry, association AS association_1 
WHERE entry.id = association_1.entry_id AND %(param_1)s = association_1.category_id
GROUP BY entry.text ORDER BY duration desc
```

However, when I try to run this query, I get the following error:

```
>>> projects.all()
[...trace back...]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Decimal' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I'm guessing SA is trying to do some processing and failing? Is there a way to get this query to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems SQLAlchemy cannot do Interval (timedelta) arithmetic when the database is MySQL.  I was able to get it working with:

```
class tsum(GenericFunction):
    type = Float()
    name = 'SUM'

projects = s.query(Entry.text, (func.t_sum(
                func.time_to_sec(func.timediff(Entry.ended, Entry.started)/60)
                  .label('duration'))
            .filter(Entry.categories.contains(work))
            .group_by(Entry.text)
            .order_by('duration desc')
```

Which returns the tuples `(text, minutes)`.